# Set computer description in Remote Desktop Connection items?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

At work I use Remote Desktop Connection in Windows 7 alot. Because of the number of computers in the organisation, every computer has a structural name like `com12345` and similar.

[image: Screenshot describing computers]

I get pretty tired of remembering which computer belongs to who and I wonder if there are any options to give a connection entry a description or tag or new name - like shown in the image above?

Answer (score 5):

You could save an RDP file for each of the machines you connect to and give the RDP file a meaningful name.

So, when you want to connect to "Kitchen Computer" you can then double-click on the "Kitchen Computer.RDP" file.

This will open Remote Desktop with the connection settings for "Kitchen Computer".

Comment: Good idea! But I prefer to right click my *Remode Desktop Icon* locked to the *task bar* and select between my pinned (+10 items) and recent connections.

Comment: Could you modify your question to include this requirement and I'll also post an alternate answer?

Answer (score 4):

To set up a local "alias" for fixed IP addresses on your local network you could include an entry into your local HOSTS file. Then it would be possible to connect to "KitchenPC" from the list of pinned connections.

[Hosts File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)

Something like this (I haven't checked the syntax so this might not be completely right)

```
# This is an example of the hosts file
127.0.0.1  localhost loopback
192.168.0.1 yourmachine
::1        localhost
```

Comment: Any way to do this if items have a port? An alias would be really nice with this app.